# Spring 14 Login issue using partner wsdl

Tags: callout, wsdl, partner, partner-wsdl

I have approval process where users will approve records only through email. Once Users approved automatically pdf will be generated.

Since there is a restriction in create pdf from Trigger or future calls directly. I am using webservice. I am getting user session using partner wsdl.

After spring 14 upgrade, these login is not working properly and pdf is not creating. I found the known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3BWAA0

any idea to resolve the issue or work around.

I have tried using Userinfo.getsession method, but there is no user logged in it is not working.